# Google Maps API V2 Android - Geocoder Issue

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, geocode

Im using google Maps API V2. In this application im attempting to get the users current location and view it on the map aswell as show the address i.e. street, city, country etc in the textView. So ass the app starts it shows your current location on the map and street address in the textView. Unfortunaly the application just crashes at the moment. Does anybody have an idea of how to resolve this, i will be extremely grateful.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Google Map
    public GoogleMap googleMap;
    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String bestProvider;
    private Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}







/**
 * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();}

    }
        }

                public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                    //Get current location
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                    //Get address from location
                    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    try {
                        addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(position.latitude, position.longitude, 1);
                        if (addresses.size()>0){

                            //Get the first address from the list and get its address lines
                            Address address = addresses.get(0);
                            String addressString = "";
                            for (int i=0;i<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++) {
                                addressString+=address.getAddressLine(i)+ " ";
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, addressString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("GEOCODER", e.getMessage(), e);
                    }

                }




                protected void onStart()
                {
                        super.onStart();

                        this.textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView);


                        this.locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                    this.bestProvider = this.locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
                    this.location = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

                    this.displayLocation(location);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onResume()
                {
                        super.onResume();
                        this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this.bestProvider,100,0,(LocationListener) this);
                        initilizeMap();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPause()
                {
                        super.onPause();
                        this.locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
                }

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                private void displayLocation(Location location)
                {
                        String locality = "";
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                        try
                        {
                                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),5);
                                for(Address address : addresses)
                                {
                                        if(address.getLocality()!=null)
                                        {
                                                locality = address.getLocality();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        catch(IOException ioException)
                        {
                                Log.e("MyApp","Exception",ioException);
                        }
                        if(!locality.isEmpty())
                        {
                                textView.append(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude()+" ("+locality+") \n");     
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                textView.append(location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude()+" ( unknown locality) \n");
                        }
                }


                public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
                {
                        this.displayLocation(location);
                }


                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
                {

                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
                {

                }


                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
                {

                }



    }
```

Logcat:

```
04-04 19:54:04.040: W/dalvikvm(27507): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42014700)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2919)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2948)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:212)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1209)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5450)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
04-04 19:54:04.045: E/AndroidRuntime(27507):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: does my method look correct

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    this.locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
}
```

`this` is an `Activity,` not a `LocationListener`

You need to pass in an actual `LocationListener` here.

Comment: what exactly do i change it to